# Angular change detection not working

Tags: linux, angular, fedora

Following the [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) I created a simple hello-world program without routing and/or http yet. Just with a service delivering a static array of mocked objects.

On Windows the change detection works fine but **not** on fedora linux (version 26 and not 27). I start the app on the cmd (Windows) / bash (Fedora) with `npm start`. As editor I use atom and the browser is in all cases firefox 57.0.

What could be the problem?

If required I could upload the (small) project somewhere. However, as I think it is not a problem related to the code as the same code works with change detection on windows I wait until somebody asks me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu, to fix this issue, after every system restart I reset watchers using this command:

```
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

It works fine for Ubuntu, I think it should work for Fedora too, because they are very close. And don't forget to rerun your Angular app after executing the command above.

Comment: GREAT! Thank you so much. It is working. Where can I read more about "watchers"?

Comment: @Mfried, sorry, I don't really know much about watchers. I just googled a little and looks like this links will give some info about it: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers, https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Linux_real-time_file_watching_errors